# Phonegap 3.0 - Android: Native Scrollbar Not Visible

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, scroll

I am currently converting the scroll behavior on a very large PhoneGap application from a third party JavaScript scrolling library to native scroll.  Everything has gone smoothly, except that the native scroll on the Android version never displays a scrollbar.

The scroll behavior works correctly, but no scrollbar is displayed to give the user feedback about the scroll position on a screen.

I suspect that this is some sort of configuration or CSS problem, but I have tried modifying CSS and other Android configuration files such as the manifest and activity files to no avail.

How do I enable a visible scrollbar using native scroll on PhoneGap Android?

Note:  **I am *not* interested in a third party scrolling solution (such as iScroll).  The conversion from iScroll is already 90% done with the exception of the visible scrollbar problem on Android.**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this myself by using Webkit scrollbar CSS that only gets applied on Android.  I add the android-scroll-bar class to the page on Android by using

```
$('html').addClass('android-scroll-bar');
```

Here is the necessary CSS:

```
.android-scroll-bar ::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 5px;}

.android-scroll-bar ::-webkit-scrollbar-track { border-radius: 10px;}

.android-scroll-bar ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { border-radius: 10px; background: rgb(169,169,169); }

.android-scroll-bar ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {background: rgb(128,128,128); }
```

Comment: How could i change the color of that bar?

Comment: the scrollbar do only change the position after scrolling is done. Is this normal? or better how do i fix this?

Comment: @user2428759: I have a scrollable div, and I have added the same class which have answered here. But this works on iOS and Nexus Android and shows the scrollbars. But the same is not working with Samsung Galaxy devices. Any idea ?

Answer (score -3):

How can i add scroll bar for Windows app, Because following code does not work in Windows app (Phonegap)

```css
android-scroll-bar ::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 5px;}

.android-scroll-bar ::-webkit-scrollbar-track { border-radius: 10px;}

.android-scroll-bar ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { border-radius: 10px; background: rgb(169,169,169); }

.android-scroll-bar ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {background: rgb(128,128,128); }
```

Comment: Windows does not use Webkit as rendering engine. Therefore, the selector will not be recognized. BTW: Your answer is a question and should be posted as one. ;-)

Comment: Ok ,  I am new to stack overflow so i m not aware of these thigings can you please click upward buttion so i can ask Questions. you made  my block by clicking on downward button