# Ionic scrollbar not showing on android device

Tags: ionic-framework

I've this code below, it works fine on chrome browser for desktop, but when I run the app on android device, I can scroll the page but the scrollbar is not visible. Can you help me? This is my code:

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title class="title title-center title-balanced">
        {{confissaoTitle}}
    </ion-nav-title>

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-content padding="true">
        <div ng-include="capitulourl"></div>
    </ion-content>

    <div class="bar bar-footer bar-positive">
        <div class="button-bar">
            <a class="button" ng-click="anterior('#/app/capitulo/{{indice.id}}/{{confissaoTitle}}/{{confissaoId}}/{{ultimoCapitulo}}')" ng-disabled="capituloId == 1">Anterior</a>
            <a class="button" ng-click="indice('#/app/capitulo/{{indice.id}}/{{confissaoTitle}}/{{confissaoId}}/{{ultimoCapitulo}}')">Índice</a>
            <a class="button" ng-click="proximo('#/app/capitulo/{{indice.id}}/{{confissaoTitle}}/{{confissaoId}}/{{ultimoCapitulo}}')" ng-disabled="ultimoCapitulo == capituloId">Próximo</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</ion-view>
```

Comment: Can you provide your `capitulourl` template?

Comment: Hi, Beat, they are a lot of pure html text files, like this: "CAPÍTULO 1 
<br><br>DA ESCRITURA SAGRADA "

Comment: These should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866285/phonegap-3-0-android-native-scrollbar-not-visible and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547329/make-scrollbar-visible-in-ionic-content-when-using-native-scroll