# ionic scrollbar is not visible in Android phone

Tags: android, ionic-framework

This issue i am facing while making android build for ionic app.
Though i have tried many suggestion which got through these following links . couldn't able to fix this . Can any1 suggest me some more suggestion . Any help i would appriciate .

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4928

[Make scrollbar visible in ionic content when using native scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547329/make-scrollbar-visible-in-ionic-content-when-using-native-scroll)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you actually tried so far that you expect to work, but does not? Does it show any errors?

Comment: No Errors yet !! but scroll bar is not getting reflected in my android app

Comment: Could it be that there's not enough displayed information to require scrollbars? Please add images from your debug tool to help us better see what you see. (There's an embed image feature just above the textbox when editing or creating a question)

Comment: I had to add ion-scrollbar and in it i added css classes to add some properties . It worked Thanks

Comment: Anytime - please do add your solution as an answer to help others.

Comment: Thanks !! I am sharing below code which worked for me :)

In html i have added following code .
    <ion-content>
 <ion-scroll  direction="y" class="theroot">
<div>

</div>

   </ion-scroll>

</ion-content>

In Css added following code 
-----

.theroot {
height: 250px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;

}

Comment: It would be much better if you create a new Answer to this Question with that content and any other notes you have. This will allow you to answer your own Question. You can put four spaces in front of each line to make a code block. Don't worry if your formatting is not good, others (including myself) can suggest edits to correct any mistakes. This will then keep this question off the review lists here and make it easier for others to find and identify what the final answer was. Additionally, other users may upvote it which will improve your site reputation.

Comment: i have created you may see now !

Answer (score 3):

try this. put this classes on the css file:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 11px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 11px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.overflow-scroll {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To correct my Ionic scroll bar woes, I added the following CSS and HTML. It's presently working in my android App.

In html file I added following contents:

```css
.theroot {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

```html
<ion-content>
<ion-scroll  direction="y" class="theroot">
<div>
</div>
</ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

### In style.css added following code

```
.theroot {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```