# Scrollbar is hidden on Android device, how to display vertical scrollbar?

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, ionic2

I have this style, and on web browser all is good, but when i run app on android device, scrollbar is hide.

```
.alert-message::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 5px;}

.alert-message::-webkit-scrollbar-track { border-radius: 10px;}

.alert-message::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { border-radius: 10px; background: rgb(169,169,169); }

.alert-message::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {background: rgb(128,128,128); }
```

Comment: Hi Bartosz, did you try this solution?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866285/phonegap-3-0-android-native-scrollbar-not-visible

I think it's related to your topic. Maybe you just need to add this in a small script:

$('html').addClass('android-scroll-bar');

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this class:

```
$('html').addClass('android-scroll-bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this script is what you need:

```
<script>
     $('html').addClass('android-scroll-bar');
</script>
```

Just add it in your header. For more information:
[Similar question](http://%20stackoverflow.com/questions/22866285/)