# How to enable scroll bar in Android Web View?

Tags: html, css, cordova, ionic2, android-webview

I'm using `Ionic 2` framework and just notices that when compiled (Android 5.1) there is no scroll bar. Scroll works fine, just doesn't show any scrollbar.

I want that scrollbar would be shown by default every time. For `Chrome` on desktop in responsive view I managed to do it with `css` like this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 5px}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background: rgb(169,169,169) }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {background: rgb(128,128,128) }
```

But on android device it's don't work.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866285/phonegap-3-0-android-native-scrollbar-not-visible